# Why does jQuery's parents/closest(selector) functions behave differently in IE8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-selectors, parents

I have a jQuery script that works perfectly fine in Chrome 11 and Firefox 4, but it appears to be broken in IE8. It appears to be related to the use of the [jQuery parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents) function with a selector. It does not return any elements when run in IE8.

I've created a simplified version of my problem which shows the same symptoms [over at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robvangroenewoud/WEdB2/), to prevent a big chunk of code here.

Can anybody tell me what might be going on here?

**UPDATE:** Using [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) seems to result in similar behavior, but seems to be more suitable in this case.

Comment: Does IE 8 support `data-` attributes at all? Does it work if you use non-`data-` attributes? And are you sure that `parents()` is what you want rather than `nearest()`?

Comment: @Craig: I started out of a working prototype trying to support IE as well, so haven't tried non-data attributes. I think you meant closest() which seems to be more what I'm looking for. I'll be looking in to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the top level elements have to be sections? It looks like you are running into one of the areas where the lack of support for HTML5 in IE8 is limiting you. If you change the sections to divs, the code works as is.

[Section support in browsers.](http://caniuse.com/#search=section)

Comment: That's it! Changing the sections to divs indeed fixes it. I'll just have to live with less semantic markup for now. Unfortunately my company will probably not upgrade to IE9 any time soon. Thanks Jeff!

Comment: I didn't know that jQuery's selector mechanism was limited by browser support, though. I should consider that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the selectors in your jsFiddle, I was able to get it to work fine in IE8 if I just got rid of the second part of the selector.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
     $('a[data-detailed]').live('click', function(event){
        var a = $(this);
        var key= a.attr('data-detailed');

        $(".detailedOverview[data-detailed="+key+"]").slideToggle('fast');
        $(".masterOverview").slideToggle('fast');
        event.preventDefault();   
    });

    $('a[href=#back]').live('click', function(event){
        var a = $(this);
        var detailedOverview= a.parents("[data-detailed]");

        $(".masterOverview").slideToggle('fast');         
        detailedOverview.slideToggle('fast');

        event.preventDefault();   
    });
});
```

In each of your selectors you had a ", fileparent" after the selector. It is not necessary to specify the parent like this and getting rid of it works. In fact you can get rid of fileparent all-together.

Comment: `fileparent` is a context to search within (if not supplied, jquery will search starting from the document root). In the case of this question, the context should be `fileParent[0]`. Without context works only if elements are unique accross document for `".detailedOverview[data-detailed="+key+"]"` selector for example.

Comment: I used to have only one section, in that case your absolutely right about not needing the fileParent. However the page is dynamically build up and as soon as there are multiple sections, the context is needed to prevent all similar overviews in other sections to be toggled as well. I guess I had over-simplified my example by only adding one section, sorry about that. I've updated the jsFiddle.