# Image width after load returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here? IE8 returns 0 for the width of these images regardless. Works fine everywhere else.

```
$('#hometown li img').load(function()
{
    var imgWidth = parseInt($(this).width());
    var percent = (99.99 * (imgWidth / 1600)) + '%';

    console.log(imgWidth) // <- Always 0 in ie8

    $(this).parent().css({ 'width': percent });
});
```

Comment: Do you get the same result if you use `1600.0`?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, but excellent thought!

Comment: Does `$('#hometown li img')` target just one image, or are there several LI's with images? Does it happen on CTRL-F5 as well (no cache) ?

Comment: That selector targets multiple images and yes, I just tried no-cache.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951804/why-does-jquerys-parents-closestselector-functions-behave-differently-in-ie8

Comment: @MESSIAH - that question is not relevant, even if the OP believed the issue was `parent()`, it wasn't, the parent element was `<section>`, which is a HTML5 element, and is not valid in IE8. `parent()` works as expected as long the markup is valid.

Comment: ^ Agreed, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching a native onload to each image seperately instead, and trigger the onload if the complete property is true to avoid caching issues :

```
$('#hometown li img').each(function() {
    this.onload = function() {
        var imgWidth = this.width();
        var percent = 99.99 * (imgWidth / 1600);

        console.log(imgWidth);

        this.parentNode.style.width = percent + '%';
    }
    if(this.complete) this.onload();
});
```